# Xml and Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I've been for numerous tutorials and I still can't seem to get this right.

I have the following XML document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<bookstore>

  <book category="COOKING">
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>30.00</price>
  </book>

  <book category="CHILDREN">
    <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
    <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>29.99</price>
  </book>

  <book category="WEB">
    <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
    <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>39.95</price>
  </book>

</bookstore>
```

I also have the folowing javascript in my HTML

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else // for IE 5/6
  {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xhttp.open("GET","book.xml",false);
xhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xhttp.responseXML;

alert(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title").nodeValue);
```

I want to be able to alert a specific title ( or all title if possible ).

How is this possible?

Comment: What do you get if you log `xmlDoc` to the _console_?

Comment: getElementsByTagName returns a node list, you can not use nodeValue on a list.

Comment: As epascarello said, you will have to iterate through the _NodeList_ returned by `getElementsByTagName` to look at individual _Nodes_.

Comment: So how can I get just the first "title" and alert it?

Comment: Loop through the nodes and filter it down to your title

Comment: Could I see what the code looks like for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So how can I get just the first "title" and alert it?

Assuming `xmlDoc`,

```
var titles = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title"); // NodeList
if (titles[0])                    // if there is an item in index 0
    alert(titles[0].textContent); // alert it's textContent
else                              // otherwise
    alert('Error: no titles');    // some error message
```

Comment: @craig sorry, assumed _nodeValue_ was the property you wanted, try with _textContent_ instead (edited).

Comment: Im assuming    _document.getElementById('booktitle1').innerHTML=(titles[0].textContent);_
 should work?